# python - http.server works on windows but doesnt on debian

Tags: python, http, debian

So I'm relatively new to python, but I am a quick learner, I think. 
For communication with one of my programs, I made this simple webserver:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import json
import os
import time

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    class user():
        def __init__(self, name, hash):
            self.name = name;
            self.hash = hash;
        def terminate(self):
            pass;
    def _set_headers(self, res=200, type="text/html", loc=False):
        self.send_response(res)
        if loc:
            self.send_header('Location', loc)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers(200)
        self.wfile.write(b"<tt><h1>UGame-Server.</h1></tt><hr>Incorrect Method.")

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self._set_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        if self.headers.get('Content-Length'):
            data = json.loads(self.rfile.read(int(self.headers.get('Content-Length'))));
        else:
            data = {};
        datas = json.dumps(data);
        if self.path == "/":
            self._set_headers(200, "text/html", "index");
            self.path = "/index";
        else:
            self._set_headers(200, "text/html");
        path = self.path[1:];
        print(path);
        import index as serverfile;
        auth=True;
        if path[:6]=="secure":
            auth=False;
            os.chdir("axs");
            if "hash" in data:
                if os.path.exists(data["hash"]+".txt") and time.time()-os.path.getmtime(data["hash"]+".txt")<43200:
                    auth=True;
                    print("Secure access from account "+data["name"]+" verified.");
                    data["user"]=self.user(data["name"],data["hash"]);
                #   del data["name"];
            else:
                if self.client_address[0]=="127.0.0.1":
                    auth=True;
                    data["user"]=self.user("admin","fake");
                    data["name"]="admin";
            os.chdir("..");
            if auth:
                psfr = open("serverdata.posdata.json", "r" );
                posdata = json.loads(psfr.read());
                psfr.close();
                if data["name"] in posdata:
                    data["user"].x = posdata[data["name"]]["x"];
                    data["user"].y = posdata[data["name"]]["y"];
                    data["user"].z = posdata[data["name"]]["z"];
                    data["user"].world = posdata[data["name"]]["world"];
        if auth:
        #   try:
            exec("global response; response = serverfile."+path+"(data);");
        #   except AttributeError:  
        #       exec('global response; response = "Method not found.";');
        else:
            exec('global response; response = "Authentification Failed.";');
        print("Sending response: "+response);
        self.wfile.write(bytes(response, 'utf8'));


def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=1103):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print('Starting httpd...');
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import argv

    if len(argv) == 2:
        run(port=int(argv[1]))
    else:
        run()
```

Now the thing is, this thing works perfectly fine on Windows and does EXACTLY what it should. But as soon as it comes to Debian, the OS my VPS in running on, which it was meant for in the first place, it crashes immediately on the first line. It appears to be unable to import **http.server** because of **hundreds** of syntax errors, coming from the internal code of *http.client*.

The first error, for example, is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/var/www/html/ugame-server/server.py", line 1, in <module>
    from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
  File "http/server.py", line 92, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "http/client.py", line 144
    _is_legal_header_name = re.compile(rb'[^:\s][^:\r\n]*').fullmatch
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

> *I have checked all available updates, my system, python and all the modules are up to date.*

- Apparently I was mistaken.

Not a single one of the errors appearing appears on windows. And I don't get it. Help is appreciated.

EDIT: Updating Debian fixed some errors, but new ones appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/var/www/html/ugame-server/server.py", line 1, in <module>
    from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
  File "/var/www/html/ugame-server/http/server.py", line 92, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/var/www/html/ugame-server/http/client.py", line 1063
    chunk = f'{len(chunk):X}\r\n'.encode('ascii') + chunk \
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What are python versions in both cases ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's 3.6 on both. At least I updated both of them using all the shell commands I know.

Comment: Can you _verify_ it ? There may be multiple versions of Python installed in OS, but the one you're using by default is one of them, maybe the one you didn't expect

Comment: And most probably you use Python 2 to run the code in the second case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.compile(rb'[^:\s][^:\r\n]*'` is invalid syntax in Python 2, so look which version you're actually using when starting the server

As per second error, f-strings are accessible startings from Python 3.6:
https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: I had, for some reason, 2.5 on the debian and 3.6 on windows. What confuses me is that, if the code is valid on 2, why *did* it work on windows and *didn't* on debian? However, I now updated the debian to 3.5, but now new errors have appeared:

Comment: ´File "/var/www/html/ugame-server/http/client.py", line 1063´
   ´ chunk = f'{len(chunk):X}\r\n'.encode('ascii') + chunk \´
                                ^
´SyntaxError: invalid syntax´

Comment: The code is _invalid_ for Python2 and valid for Python3 only

Comment: Oh, that way around it makes more sense. I read it wrong, sorry.

Comment: Also I added the new errors that appear now as an edit.

Comment: Not sure what you ask. This one is invalid in python2 too

Comment: For all other moments - please take time to test portions of code you have errors in with both python versions and go from there

Comment: But the error appears on python 3.5. I'm absolutely sure this time. I'm not sure if I'm understanding something wrong, but I'm executing the code with 3.5.

Comment: Edit the file you have an error in and add the code before the line:`import sys; print(sys.version_info)`

Comment: It says 3.5.2, as expected.

Comment: Okay well. I couldn't figure out how to install 3.6, and I felt like 3,5 will suffice. Now that you told me I needed it, I figured out how to install it, and now it works. I'm sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: Well, if it helped, then my time wasn't wasted )